# Blueimp jquery file upload with angular submit all form but not just files

Tags: angularjs, jquery-file-upload

On some entity editing page there is a section with image management - image management implemented via blueimp jQuery file uploader + angular plugin.

i cant put image management in form cause nested forms are not allowed.
Using code from example:

```
.form-group{'data-ng-app' =>'demo', 'data-ng-controller' => 'DemoFileUploadController', 'data-file-upload' => 'options', 'ng-init' => "options.url='#{add_image_promotion_path(@promotion)}'", 'data-ng-class' => "{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}"}
  .col-sm-6
    .fileupload-buttonbar
      %span.btn.btn-success.fileinput-button
        %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
        %span Add image...
        %input{type: :file, multiple: 'multiple', name: 'image'}/
      %button.btn.btn-primary.start{type: :submit, 'data-ng-click' => 'submit()'}
        %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-upload
        %span Start upload
      %button.btn.btn-warning.cancel{type: :reset, 'data-ng-click' =>'cancel()'}
        %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-ban-circle
        %span Cancel upload
      %span.fileupload-process
```

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Controller and everything is like in example, the only difference that i'm using div instead of form.

The problem is after i'm adding file and click upload - whole form submission occurs, but i need just file uploading.
Please advice.

Comment: Is this coffeescript or ruby or something? I don't really understand any of the code sample.

Comment: Try changing your button type from submit to button and then clicking it won't submit the form but the ng-click will still execute.

Answer (score 0):

When you pick a `file` each file is stacked in an `queue` array. You can take a `file` from `queue` and perform `file.$submit()` in `ng-click`.

**Below is an example for uploading only the `last picked` file**

```
  %button.btn.btn-primary.start{type: :button, 'data-ng-click' => 'queue[queue.length - 1].$submit()'}
    %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-upload
    %span Start upload
  %button.btn.btn-warning.cancel{type: :reset, 'data-ng-click' =>'queue[queue.length - 1].$cancel()'}
    %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-ban-circle
    %span Cancel upload
```